# In delphi firemonkey how can i use a TLabel to display date and time

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In delphi im trying to display time and date on a TLabel using Ttimer component but i cant get this code to work

```
begin
    clock.Caption := TimeToStr(Time)
end;
```

clock is the TLabel name

Comment: What does *cant get this code to work* mean? In what way isn't it working? What is the specific question you're asking?

Comment: @KenWhite i keep getting undeclared identifier caption error

Comment: Then [edit] your question and add that information there, where it belongs. It's your responsibility to clearly describe the problem and ask the question, and we can't do our part trying to help you until you've done so. You should also include enough code to provide context, so that we know what variables are and where the code is being executed. See [mre] and [ask].

Answer (score 4):

FMX Labels do not have a Caption property. Instead, they have a Text property.

Try

```
begin
    clock.Text := TimeToStr(Time)
end;
```

Comment: @CHRSSGGG which you would have known had you [read the TLabel documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TLabel), or even just looked at the properties of the TLabel in the Object Inspector of the Form Designer.